# Trying to dynamically allocate a class in Scala

Tags: scala, dynamic

Anyone have an idea of how to dynamically allocate a class in Scala (2.10)?
I've got some class MyClass.   I'm using Akka (2.0) and I'd REALLY like to be able to do something like:

```
classnames = List[String]("fqcn", "fqcn", fqcn"....]
for (name <- classnames) {
     val clazz = classLoader.load(name)
     val actRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[clazz])
}
```

However, there are other limits on Akka.   So the best I can do (I think) is:

```
val activeClasses = HashMap([String, String, ActorRef]
     ("commonname" -> 
       "Fqcn", actorOf(Props[new classobject]])
  )
```

where classobject is the literal class, not a name reference for the class loader.   I literally have to have the class compiled somewhere and do the

actorOf(Props[**new** classobject****])

This seems very ugly -- is there a nicer, more elegant way to do this?

Comment: ** it's not ugly, it's plain wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since clazz is from the classLoader, it 's not possible to use Props[] to create ActorRef

so use `Props.apply` instead

```
actorOf(Props(clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor]))
```

Comment: @toscho at least it can pass compile. Since clazz is from the classLoader so is not possible to use Props[] to create ActorRef

Comment: Please do not hide valuable information in a comment, edit your answer instead. :)

Comment: This will compile, but fail at runtime. You can't create instances of actors outside of the actor system. Use `Props(clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor])` instead.

Comment: @drexin please help me to understand why it's not the same
    `val instance = clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor]
    actorOf(Props(instance))`
    
    `actorOf(Props(clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor])))`

Comment: `Props.apply` takes a call by name parameter `=> Actor`, so it will not be evaluated when Props is created, but later somewhere in the `actorOf` call.

Comment: @drexin thx for explain, after go though the code, i found the problem. key point is `protected[akka] implicit val context: ActorContext` in Actor.scala

Answer (score 3):

Fixing the first sample you provided, see the comments:

```
classnames = List[String]("fqcn", "fqcn", "fqcn"....) // close ( with ) not ]
for (name <- classnames) {
     val clazz = classLoader.forName(name) // forName is what loads a class
     //val actRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[clazz]) // still wrong I will explain later
}
```

The second sample has a few more issues.

First `HashMap([String, String, ActorRef]("commonname" -> "Fqcn", someThing))`, it's close to be right but with a few key syntactic mistakes.

In Scala the `[]` is used to declare or define type parameters, it seems our case in hand is a matter of definition, in other words, we want to state what type paramaters. There are only a few places Scala allows placing type parameters, it's right classes after class instanciation (e.g `new HashMap[String, Int]`) and in method call (e.g `list.map[String](...)`.

So, placing the type parameter as in `HashMap[String, String, ActorRef](...)` would be valid Scala syntax and since HashMap is companion object it would end up after desugaring something like `HashMap.apply[String, String, ActorRef](...)`.

But this expression still have a big problem, HashMap only take two type parameters, one for the keys and one for the values. Looking at your code it seems that the desired key is a tuple. So to make it work: `HashMap[(String, String), ActorRef](...)`

Now for the last fix `Props[new classobject]`, again confusion regarding type parameters. Type parameters takes **types** not instances, any 'new something' would be creating a instance of something. You have to do `Props[SomeClass]`. As a quick side not the term "class object" usually refers to instance of a class, not the class itself.

A syntactic valid version of the second sample:

```
val activeClasses = HashMap[(String, String), ActorRef](
   ("commonname" ->  "Fqcn", actorOf(Props[SomeClass]))
)
```

Coming back to the first sample and this particular line:

```
val actRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[clazz])
```

`clazz` here is a instance of Class[_], again the above wouldn't even be valid code. It seems that `Props.apply[T <: ActorRef]...` requires a type and it will take care of instantiating it for you. But you only have Class[_]'s containing the classes. How to solve this? It happens there is another Props.apply that instead takes constructs for the actor classes that will take of the instantiation, look it's signature:

```
def apply(creator: ⇒ Actor)
```

Why not use this one?

```
classnames = List[String]("fqcn", "fqcn", "fqcn"....)
for (name <- classnames) {
     val clazz = classLoader.forName(name)
     val actRef = 
        actorSystem.actorOf(Props( clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor] )) 
}
```

Assuming the second sample will somehow rely classes from the first:

```
val activeClasses = HashMap[(String, String), ActorRef](
   ("commonname" ->  "Fqcn", 
     actorOf(Props( clazz.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Actor] ) )
)
```

A few comments about these samples:

- Both type parameters are unnecessary. The compiler can infer then for you.
- Instead of using `(a -> b, c)` for defining a tuple whose first element is a tuple, you can use `a -> b ->`, which will result into `((a,b),c)`. The `->` is left associative.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered on the Akka Mailinglist: https://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/6823203b3c8470be/8ad21fcfb39b0e25?lnk=gst&q=dynamicAccess

In short, Create an Akka Extension that deals with dynamic class loading and get the ExtendedActorSystem that is passed in, obtain its DynamicAccess through the "dynamicAccess" method and load the class using that. This will use the same ClassLoader that is used for all dynamic classloading inside Akka, which is the same ClassLoader as you pass to the ActorSystem.